# Customize default InfoWindow in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am wondering if it is possible to customize the default InfoWindow that pops up when the user clicks on various businesses that Google displays on its default map (see screenie). I would like to add functionality to let people "pin" these locations if they have stumbled on them while just browsing the map.

[image: the map example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to listen to any click event on the POI icons so overriding/modifying the info window is not possible.

File a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label%3aApiType-Javascript3) asking for it.

Comment: It was filed and recently fixed: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4797

Answer (score 0):

i don't know customizing the functionality of infowindow, but by using google infobox we can customize the look, from that you can try the functionality. because infobox uses pure html code.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox.js

Comment: Yes, but you cannot override event that is opened when a user clicks a POI icon so you won't be able to open a infobox/infobubble instead.