# Google Maps API v3 get clicked place's information

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've read a lot about `InfoWindow` on google maps but it only says how to create an info window. What I want to do is obtain information on an already-existing place.

For example: If I use `places` library, I'd make a request and it give me an object with the place name, human-readable address, latitude, longitude, etc.

I want exactly that information when I click on an already existing place. How can I achieve this?

**Edit.** An use case of what I want would be the following:
I am navigating on the map, zooming and panning until I find a place. If I click that place, the Map would show me its information on a `InfoWindow`. That info I'd like to retrieve via a callback function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486868/click-event-listener-on-styled-map-icons-and-labels

Comment: Oh there is no way to do that. Yes, this is a duplicate question, please close, and sorry; I searched about an hour and a half and didn't find anything