# Google Map - Which event when click on a place

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Sorry for my bad English!
I have spent more than a day for web search about this, but i have not found the solution yet. Please give me a suggestion.
I'm now working with google maps api. I've got a place autocomplete sample here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

As the attached image, the place autocomplete feature works perfectly. When I enter the key word [Sydney distance education] --> click on the first  suggestion --> the **marker** was moved to the specified place. I can get more detailed information from the marker variable.

This is the screen: http://www.imagesup.net/pt-1314056232011.png

When i click to the specified place on the map, it display a InfoWindow. I don't know which event should I need to listen to help me getting more detailed information of that place.
I have tried this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    alert('OK');
});
```

But the event is fired only when I click to another location which does not have viewport

Comment: It is not very clear what you actually want. Can you explain more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486868/click-event-listener-on-styled-map-icons-and-labels/21488643#21488643

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234106/how-to-get-a-click-event-when-a-user-clicks-a-business-place-on-the-map/24234818#24234818

Comment: Thank you all. The two link posted by @Dr.Molle is exactly what I thought