# Clicking on markers on embedded Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a webapp and want my users to be able to click a marker on the map and grab the address from the small window it brings up. These are the markers that are already built into the map, not ones that I have added, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPVOv.png

I keep finding things for markers that you have added. I do not know how to access these markers.  Presumably I want to do this for the onclick event of markers and be able to grab the information somehow. But I have no idea how to do anything with these markers.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Those are "POIs".  You can't access that data programmatically, although I don't know why your user wouldn't be able to "grab the address" from it.  The only control you have over those is whether they are shown or not (with Styled Maps).

Comment: That's unfortunate. I was going with they can search for whatever and click the marker and it automatically adds it to the address field just to be more convenient. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [click event listener on styled map icons and labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486868/click-event-listener-on-styled-map-icons-and-labels/21488643#21488643)

Comment: NB: you're using an embedded map; you have even less control over what happens on its events and styling than if you were using the Maps API v3 to add the map to your site.