# Google Autocomplete: Choose alternative place selected from map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-maps-autocomplete

### Current Situation

I've implemented a Google Autocomplete text box into a web page, so that users can select a Google Place, and store that place/address information against their account. 
*Basically crossing Google's [Place Autocomplete demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) with their [Place Autocomplete Address demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)*

From the autocomplete "search" box, the user searches for an place (in this case, an `establishment` type). They then get a list of some closest-match options - and can select the right one from the list.

When they "select" a place, this raises a `place_changed` event.

From this event, I've been able to hook up a listener, which shows a map marker at the selected `place` and pops up an `InfoWindow`.

I've changed the "default" `InfoWindow` to my own, which allows the user to click a "Use" button if they so wish - which some JavaScript then takes care of and stores necessary data in some fields. *Essentially, everything is done as per Google's documentation*.

Everything's working hunky-dory, as I would like (yippee!).

Here's a sample:

[image: Autocomplete with place selected]

---

### Consider this...

Now, let's say that the user has selected a "match" from the autocomplete dropdown. A map marker is added and the map is then focused to it, and the `InfoWindow` with "Use" button pops up (as above).

However, they decide not to "Use" it - they've seen another nearby place they wish to use.

From the map, the user can click on said alternative place, and another `InfoWindow` pops up, displaying the address and a link to "View on Google Maps".

Something like this:

[image: Autocomplete alternative place selected]

**Note:** I've noticed the content of the `InfoWindow` can sometimes vary on the special types of establishment - such as railway stations *(the address isn't shown - just some symbols to signify it being a railway station)*. I'm not *too* fussed about this, as hopefully the answer to my question will render this void.

---

### The Issue

It's obvious to see that clicking on a different location just brings up this "alternative" `InfoWindow` - I presume an event is fired and Google' JS handles it by launching another `InfoWindow` at the selected place.

I think it would be a **much** better user experience if the user were able to "Use" this other location they've clicked on, if they so desire. *They currently would have to "search again" for that other location, essentially to end up at the same result as the first image.*

Nowhere on the face of the Internet, am I able to find a way of manipulating clicking on an alternate place.

I've tried searching for an event to listen to, and then handle (in the same way I'm showing my custom `InfoWindow` from `place_changed`, through my own callback function).

---

### What can I do?

I need to know the following:

- What event is fired when an "alternative" location is selected from the map?
- Does this event contain a `place` object, like in the `place_changed` event args?
- If so, could I hookup to this event, passing said `place` into my existing JavaScript function which sets the map marker and opens the `InfoWindow`?

---

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions - it's gratefully received, as always.

Comment: Probably this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486868/click-event-listener-on-styled-map-icons-and-labels/21488643#21488643) can help.