# Google Map POI information window closeclick event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is a closeclick event triggered when a google map POI information window is closed?

If so, how do I listen for it?

If not, is there are way to learn when a POI information window is closed?

Answer (score -1):

There is no `closeclick` event on the "native" POI infowindow.

Related question: [click event listener on styled map icons and labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486868/click-event-listener-on-styled-map-icons-and-labels)

You can create your own InfoWindow when those icons are clicked and add the `closeclick` listener to those.

Note: that will require a call to the places service to get the information to display in the InfoWindow (and deciding what you want to display and how you want to format the information displayed).

[Proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tbL1fpsz/)

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    // New York, NY, USA (40.7127753, -74.0059728)
    center: {
      lat: 40.7127753,
      lng: -74.0059728
    },
    zoom: 14,
  });
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    alert("closeclick");
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    if (e.placeId) {
      // Calling e.stop() on the event prevents the default info window from
      // showing.
      // If you call stop here when there is no placeId you will prevent some
      // other map click event handlers from receiving the event.
      e.stop();
      console.log(e.placeId);
      const request = {
        placeId: e.placeId,
        fields: ["name", "formatted_address", "place_id", "geometry"],
      };
      const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          infowindow.setContent(
            "<div><strong>" +
            place.name +
            "</strong><br>" +
            "Place ID: " +
            place.place_id +
            "<br>" +
            place.formatted_address +
            "</div>"
          );
          infowindow.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          infowindow.setOptions({
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -10)
          })
          infowindow.open(map);
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**second (more dangerous) option**

A more dangerous option (depends on overriding the `.setContent` method of the `InfoWindow` as described in the related question: [click event listener on styled map icons and labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486868/click-event-listener-on-styled-map-icons-and-labels)).

1. Overwrite either the `.setContent` or `.open` method on the `InfoWindow` class
2. capture a reference to the infowindow that is opened when the [`IconMouseEvent`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#IconMouseEvent) fires
3. add a `closeclick` listener on the captured `InfoWindow`
4. remove the event listener function and replace the overridden method with the original

Note: this will only capture the `InfoWindow` [closeclick](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.closeclick) that is fired when the 'x' is clicked on the `InfoWindow`, not when it is closed because another `InfoWindow` opens.

**Code:**

```
  var iconIw;
  //store the original setContent-function
  var fx = google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setContent;
  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    // if infowindow for Icon, override setContent, add closeclick listener, replace setContent
    if (e.placeId) {
      console.log(e.placeId);
      //override the built-in setContent-method
      google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setContent = function(content) {
        iconIw = this;
        google.maps.event.addListener(iconIw, 'closeclick', function() {
          alert("closeclick");
        });
        listener.remove();
        //run the original setContent-method
        fx.apply(this, arguments);
        google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setContent = fx;
      };
    }
  })
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/tbL1fpsz/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    // New York, NY, USA (40.7127753, -74.0059728)
    center: {
      lat: 40.7127753,
      lng: -74.0059728
    },
    zoom: 14,
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  marker.addListener('click', function(e) {
    infowindow.setContent("<b>Test</b>");
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  })
  var iconIw;
  //store the original setContent-function
  var fx = google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setContent;
  var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    // if infowindow for Icon, override setContent, add closeclick listener, replace setContent
    if (e.placeId) {
      console.log(e.placeId);
      //override the built-in setContent-method
      google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setContent = function(content) {
        iconIw = this;
        google.maps.event.addListener(iconIw, 'closeclick', function() {
          alert("closeclick");
        });
        listener.remove();
        //run the original setContent-method
        fx.apply(this, arguments);
        google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.setContent = fx;
      };
    }
  })
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```